# r - analogous sp method for raster::calc OR method for computing sp::over with sp and raster object

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

The core of my problem is that I want to minimize the number of times I need to convert an object between sp format (i.e. SpatialPixelsDataFrame) and Raster* format.

The task is the following: I start with a list of SPixDF (since this is the output of an external function I don't have control over) objects and I need to do two things with them.

1. I need to average them together into a single object. The solution needs to be generalizable (i.e. handle lists of varying length). Basically, I can't figure out a way to do raster::calc() with SPixDF objects.
2. The reason I need the solution for #1 is because the next step involves overlaying points on the resulting averaged SPixDF surface (i.e. sp::over). And sp::over() can't overlay SpatialPoints data on data in Raster* format.

```
## Data set-up ##
# grid data
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
gridded(meuse.grid) = TRUE
spplot(meuse.grid)

meuse.grid.list <- list(meuse.grid, meuse.grid, meuse.grid)

# point data 
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")


### Analysis steps (involving 2 conversions) ### 

# Convert listed SPixDF to listed RasterLayer
meuse.raster.list <- lapply(meuse.grid.list, function(x) raster(x, layer=5, values=T))

meuse.raster.stack <- stack(meuse.raster.list)  # list of RasterLayers to RasterStack

# task #1
meuse.cmbnd <- calc(meuse.raster.stack, mean)  # average together individual rasters

# Convert back to SPixDF 
meuse.cmbnd.spdf <- as(meuse.cmbnd, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame") 

# task #2
# overlay points on SPixDf grid
Result <- over(meuse, meuse.cmbnd.spdf)
```

If sp::over() could handle Raster* objects, then I would just convert the initial object once (to Raster*) and do steps 1 and 2 in that format. So essentially the problem is that I can't figure out a GENERALIZABLE way of conducting both steps in the same format (either sp or Raster).

If you think of anything I would be most grateful!

*P.S. The background of this is that this operation is currently written in a function I'm working on, and I am trying to speed it up. But because I have to keep switching between sp and Raster classes, the solution I have becomes slower than the existing formulation.*